# How to SHIFT-RET to open link in a new tab while preserving RET behavior in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, tabbar

In org-mode
I want to open link in a new tab when I press `Shift-RET`.
I'm currently using `RET` to open link.

I tried to use `(setf (cdr (assoc 'file org-link-frame-setup)) 'find-file-other-tab)`.
That makes file to open in a new link. But It removes original `RET` behavior which opens in current tab.

I use emacs 29.1 and tab is built-in `tab-bar-mode` and evil mode.